# RichPush Notifications on IOS are blocking regular pushes

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios, push-notification, react-native

**React Native. iOS only:**

I installed rich push notification extensions according to documentation [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/push-notifications/rich-notifications.html). 
I have 4 targets, so I created 4 extensions "rich", 4 separate Bundle Identifiers "xxx.rich" and 4 separate provisioning profiles "xxx.rich".

The provisioning profile is explicit and has this:

[image]

(**I am not sure that I need to do that for the extension**, though).

The provisioning profile of the main target "xxx" has all certificates (dev and .p12). .p12 we use at SFMC to send pushes.

The problem is as soon as I add the extension for rich pushes, my app stops to receive all notifications in production (enriched or simple), but still works on development mode.
When I remove extension - everything works fine in production.

Please advise, what this can be.

I will be happy to provide more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest working on one target at a time.

After adding one notification extension, make sure that Notification Target is signed by the same Managed Profile as the project target you are expecting to use it with. Also make sure the correct profiles (and associated certs) are assigned for debug and release signing in the Notification Target.

Then make sure the Target that you want to use that Notification Extension has the capability added in their signing and capabilities tab with their appropriate profile.

Run and verify, and move on to the next one.

> (I am not sure that I need to do that for the extension, though).

The Notification Target itself should not need the push notification capability added.

> The provisioning profile of the main target "xxx" has all certificates (dev and >.p12). .p12 we use at SFMC to send pushes.

When you say main target, are you referring to your Release(production) target? If you only have one release target then you may only be needing one Notification Service Extension Target.